# How to populate the tokens used for a Scheduled Reminder in the Activity

Tags: scheduled-reminders, tokens, activity

Scheduled Reminders allow one to "Record activity for automated email" which is great. But if tokens are used in the Reminder, these are not populated in the Activity that is created.

How would one improve civicrm so that the Activity actually records what was sent out, rather than just showing the token name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a JIRA ticket now [CRM-20361](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20361) and will hopefully be in the next release.